# Android Mobile Ads Banner size for tablets

Tags: android, admob, double-click

I ama using Google Mobile Ads SDK and Google Double Click for Publisher for serving house ad campaigns.

This is my XML code for ad:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="my_add_unit_id" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView>
```

As you can see I use SMART_BANNER, so I upload image ads with 300x50 and 800x90 for phone and tablet ads.

This works very well on phone and ad is visible, but on the tablet I can not see ad.

How I can solve this?

Comment: What do you mean with "I upload image ads"?? That should be working anyway... maybe you have a tablet layout you forgot to update or to add the ad?

Comment: I am using house ad campaigns, so I need to upload my own images for ads. https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3210452?hl=en

Comment: Dud you find any solution for this? I'm using ad networks and using just 320x50 creative and can't see ads on tablets.

Comment: @Zookey I'm still stuck at this problem. It would change my life if you could please share if you were able to solve it and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use just 300x50 as smart banner I think. Should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

To set the size of PublisherAdView for tablet devices try following.

```
publisherAdView.setAdSizes(AdSize.FULL_BANNER,AdSize.LEADERBOARD);
```